# Hangfire: The type does not contain a method with signature

Tags: c#, hangfire, fire-and-forget

I have a web application which has Page1.aspx that does task1 and then enqueue task2 to scheduler in fireAndforget manner.

I am using Hangfire and everything is installed and **worked correctly but only once** when `doLongJob()` had no parameters (while testing). Then I added a parameter (and I will be adding more).
After that I am facing these [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxPev.jpg)

Page1.aspx.cs

```
string strMsgID = //task1 returns a value;
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => doLongJob(strMsgID));

public void doLongJob(string strMsgID)
{
    int status = //task2(strMsgID);
    while( status == 2)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        status = //task2(strMsgID);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using Hangfire;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(erp.Startup))]
namespace erp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.UseHangfireDashboard();

            app.UseHangfireServer();

        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseStorage(new MySqlStorage("hangfire"));
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and turned out that I was connecting to a different storage

Comment: How do I identify that ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, in my case I changed the code few weeks ago where I introduced new parameter and did a new deployment to kubenetes and I forgot to delete the old deployment so when some of the request was going to the old pod I was getting this error but after few retries in Hangfier it was successful.

I deleted the old kubernetes deployment and it worked for me.

PS: Both new and old deployment were pointing to the same hangfire queue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it turned out to be from the storage connection.

In your code, I think you are passing a string `"hangfire"` while you should pass the connection string

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseStorage(new MySqlStorage(connectionString));
```

You could find more options for MySQL configuration with hangfire [here](https://github.com/arnoldasgudas/Hangfire.MySqlStorage)

Comment: hangfire is the name of a connectionstring in the `web.config` file. So I think it's perfectly valid. And `UseStorage` accepts a name too. http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/index.html

Comment: Please try answering this too. Thanks in advance.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789937

Answer (score 0):

Did you double-check the date on the failed job?

I had a similar issue - turned out I was just looking at the same failed job from before. Because it was the most recent failed job, I didn't think to check if it was older than it looked.

Comment: yes...i used `DateTime` to print date and time as well.